# Unicode characters not displayed properly with PHP and Vertica db

Tags: php, pdo, unicode, odbc, vertica

**Summary**

I'm trying to query a Vertica database using PHP 7.0.9 and PDO via ODBC connection, but special characters such as accented letters and the EURO symbol are not displayed properly in the generated HTML page.

According to the [Vertica docs](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Other/UnicodeCharacterEncoding.htm):

> All input data received by the database server is expected to be in UTF-8, and all data output by Vertica is in UTF-8

**Environment Setup**

OS is CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 with kernel 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64

PHP 7.0.9 packages installed:

```
php70w-cli-7.0.9-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-7.0.9-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-pear-1.10.1-1.w7.noarch
php70w-odbc-7.0.9-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-mbstring-7.0.9-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-common-7.0.9-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-process-7.0.9-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-xml-7.0.9-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-pecl-xdebug-2.4.0-1.w7.x86_64
php70w-pdo-7.0.9-1.w7.x86_64
```

Additional packages:

```
unixODBC-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64
vertica-client-7.2.3-0.x86_64
```

**Relevant configuration files:**

/etc/vertica.ini

```
[Driver]
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
ODBCInstLib=/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so
ErrorMessagesPath=/opt/vertica
LogLevel=4
LogPath=/tmp
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[HPVertica]
Description = Vertica ODBC Driver
Driver = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so

[ODBC]
Threading = 1
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
Test_Vertica = "Test Vertica"

[Test_Vertica]
Description = Test Vertica
Driver = HPVertica
Database = VMart
Servername = <redacted>
UID = <redacted>
PWD = <redacted>
Port = 5433
```

**Test Case**

If I create a table with special characters and query it, the results are displayed correctly in the terminal (environment variable `$LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`):

```
# /opt/vertica/bin/vsql -h <redacted> -d VMart -U dbadmin
VMart=> create table stackoverflow(str varchar(100));
VMart=> insert into stackoverflow(str) values ('àèìòù €uro');
VMart=> commit;

# /opt/vertica/bin/vsql -h <redacted> -d VMart -U dbadmin -c 'select * from stackoverflow'
    str
------------
 àèìòù €uro
(1 row)

# echo 'select * from stackoverflow' | isql Test_Vertica
SQL> select * from stackoverflow
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str                                                                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| àèìòù €uro                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
SQLRowCount returns 1
1 rows fetched
```

However, this simple PHP script will send garbage to the user agent:

```
<?php    
$dbconn = new PDO('odbc:Test_Vertica');
$sql = 'select * from stackoverflow';
$statement = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
var_dump($results);
```

Output in terminal:

```
# php /var/www/html/stackoverflow.php
/var/www/html/stackoverflow.php:8:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'str' =>
    string(17) "àèìòù €uro"
  }
}
```

Output in browser (also tried in latest Chrome and IE):

```
# elinks -dump http://localhost/stackoverflow.php
 /var/www/html/stackoverflow.php:10:
 array (size=1)
   0 =>
     array (size=1)
       'str' => string '..... .uro' (length=10)
```

It appears that instead of the special characters, the "SUB" ASCII code (hex 1A) is sent to the user agent. Some browser display it as a dot, others as a space.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `AddDefaultCharset Off` to let the browser guess the encoding?

Comment: @woot: I tried setting `AddDefaultCharset Off` to `httpd.conf` but nothing changed